# StackExchange-like flag system for WordPress

Tags: plugins

Is there a plug-in that can incorporate a StackExchange-like flag system on a WordPress blog?

Then registered users can flag an article/post so that the admin or moderator can review the post later and decide whether the post should be published or not.

Comment: I couldn't find one after a quick google search. May need to be a custom job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still dint found any separate plugin for the same. However i did the same by doing some modifications in [My Favorite](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/) plugin

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search turned up a plug-in called "[Report Post](http://code.google.com/p/reportport/)."  Though it hasn't been updated since 2008 and, according to [a thread in the WP support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/flag-post-plugin), you might need to tweak the code a bit to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably work with one of the contact form type plugins with AJAX to have it pop up when the user clicks an icon and have it auto fill the post title in the subject line.